# Is it possible to add custom shipping address in order email templates in custom module OrderSender.php

Tags: magento2, order-email

> Here i want to add custom shipping address in order Email templates
>   programmatically using
>   magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender/OrderSender.php i.e.
>   overriding this file in custom module.If Anyone have idea please guide
>   me.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender;

use Magento\Payment\Helper\Data as PaymentHelper;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\Template;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order as OrderResource;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;

/**
 * Class OrderSender
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class OrderSender extends Sender
{
    /**
     * @var PaymentHelper
     */
    protected $paymentHelper;

    /**
     * @var OrderResource
     */
    protected $orderResource;

    /**
     * Global configuration storage.
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $globalConfig;

    /**
     * @var Renderer
     */
    protected $addressRenderer;

    /**
     * Application Event Dispatcher
     *
     * @var ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $eventManager;

    /**
     * @param Template $templateContainer
     * @param OrderIdentity $identityContainer
     * @param Order\Email\SenderBuilderFactory $senderBuilderFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param PaymentHelper $paymentHelper
     * @param OrderResource $orderResource
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $globalConfig
     * @param Renderer $addressRenderer
     * @param ManagerInterface $eventManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template $templateContainer,
        OrderIdentity $identityContainer,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilderFactory $senderBuilderFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        Renderer $addressRenderer,
        PaymentHelper $paymentHelper,
        OrderResource $orderResource,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $globalConfig,
        ManagerInterface $eventManager
    ) {
        parent::__construct($templateContainer, $identityContainer, $senderBuilderFactory, $logger, $addressRenderer);
        $this->paymentHelper = $paymentHelper;
        $this->orderResource = $orderResource;
        $this->globalConfig = $globalConfig;
        $this->addressRenderer = $addressRenderer;
        $this->eventManager = $eventManager;
    }

    /**
     * Sends order email to the customer.
     *
     * Email will be sent immediately in two cases:
     *
     * - if asynchronous email sending is disabled in global settings
     * - if $forceSyncMode parameter is set to TRUE
     *
     * Otherwise, email will be sent later during running of
     * corresponding cron job.
     *
     * @param Order $order
     * @param bool $forceSyncMode
     * @return bool
     */
    public function send(Order $order, $forceSyncMode = false)
    {
        $order->setSendEmail(true);

        if (!$this->globalConfig->getValue('sales_email/general/async_sending') || $forceSyncMode) {
            if ($this->checkAndSend($order)) {
                $order->setEmailSent(true);
                $this->orderResource->saveAttribute($order, ['send_email', 'email_sent']);
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            $order->setEmailSent(null);
            $this->orderResource->saveAttribute($order, 'email_sent');
        }

        $this->orderResource->saveAttribute($order, 'send_email');

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare email template with variables
     *
     * @param Order $order
     * @return void
     */
    protected function prepareTemplate(Order $order)
    {
        $transport = [
            'order' => $order,
            'billing' => $order->getBillingAddress(),
            'payment_html' => $this->getPaymentHtml($order),
            'store' => $order->getStore(),
            'formattedShippingAddress' => $this->getFormattedShippingAddress($order),
            'formattedBillingAddress' => $this->getFormattedBillingAddress($order),
        ];
        $transportObject = new DataObject($transport);

        /**
         * Event argument `transport` is @deprecated. Use `transportObject` instead.
         */
        $this->eventManager->dispatch(
            'email_order_set_template_vars_before',
            ['sender' => $this, 'transport' => $transportObject, 'transportObject' => $transportObject]
        );

        $this->templateContainer->setTemplateVars($transportObject->getData());

        parent::prepareTemplate($order);
    }

    /**
     * Get payment info block as html
     *
     * @param Order $order
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getPaymentHtml(Order $order)
    {
        return $this->paymentHelper->getInfoBlockHtml(
            $order->getPayment(),
            $this->identityContainer->getStore()->getStoreId()
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why you need to add `custom shipping address in order Email templates`. Because the order data contains the shipping address already.

Comment: You should try with observer: `email_order_set_template_vars_before`.